# Render and display .iBook file in an iPad app

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

I need to render and display an .iBook file in my iPad app. I was wondering if there are any .iBook file viewers available out there? Or if I can convert the .iBook file to HTML5?

Comment: Can you provide input on what you have already tried and what is not working?

Comment: I am just researching as of now and considering the options I have.

Comment: .ibook is a proprietary apple format.  If you want to dig into it's guts, it's probably a wrapper around an ebook file, and those are easy to parse (because they include a dictionary of chapters and encodings as a spine file).